# Is the function here an onto function for its given domain?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I have been given to prove that $f:(- \infty, -1] \rightarrow (- \infty, 3]$ defined by $f(x) = x^3-3x+2$ is not onto.

Now I found that the function is increasing in its given domain, and it's range is $(- \infty, 4]$

The definition of an onto function is that "if $f:A \rightarrow B$ then every element of B must have a pre image in A"

Here, that implies, every element of $(- \infty, 3]$ must have a pre image in the domain right? Isn't that what's happening? Then why isn't this an onto function exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is wrong. $f$ is not a function from $(-\infty, -1]$ into $(-\infty, 3]$ since it takes values outside $(-\infty, 3]$.

Perhaps they wanted to ask if $(-\infty, 3]$ is contained in the range of $f$ when the codomain of $f$ is taken as $\mathbb R$. In that case the answer is YES.

Comment: So it is an onto function in this given domain and codomain right?

Comment: It is not a properly defined function and you cannot say whether is it onto or not.

Comment: Why is it not a properly defined function? The definition of function is that it takes only one element in B for every element in A where B is the codomain and A is the domain. That is satisfied here right? It takes values outside the codomain, but why does that matter?

Comment: The vertical line test is satisfied in the given domain and codomain

Comment: Oh I got it, codomain can never be a subset of range. Thanks

Comment: It should assign a value in the codmain for every element in the domain. That is also a requirment for a function. @Techie5879

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)$ attains maximum value at $x=-1$ and $f(-1)=4$

Sine the codomain of function is $(-\infty,3]$ which doesn't contains the image of $x=-1$, there $f$ is not a function.

Since it is not a function we cannot talk whether it is injection, surjection or any other type

However if the codomain would have been $(-\infty,4]$, then it would be a bijection.

Comment: Yes thanks this just clicked in my mind that codomain can never be a subset of range.

Comment: @Techie5879 Yes we can say it in that way also, for given domain the range will be $(-\infty,4]$ which is not a proper subset of codomain

Comment: @Techie5879 The codomain can, in fact, be a subset of the range, provided they are equal to each other. Equal sets are subsets of each other.

Comment: @AnkitSaha Yes I edited my comment

Comment: @AnkitSaha Yes my statement should be amended to "codomain cannot be a proper subset of range"